# set of products of rank-k matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Derive the convex hull of the set of rank k outer products:
$\mathcal{D}=\{XX^T:X\in\Re^{b\times k},\text{rank}(X)=k\}$.

Question:

By definition, $\text{Conv}(\mathcal{D})=\{\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_iX_iX_i^T:X_i\in\mathcal{D},\forall i=1,\cdots,n;\forall n\in N\}$.

Is there some descriptions or characterization of elements in $\text{Conv}(\mathcal{D})$? I cannot see it.

I can see the element in $\text{Conv}(\mathcal{D})$ should be positive semi-definite. Anything else?

Thank you!

Comment: Think about "extreme" elements of $D$ itself. Like those containing $1$ and $0$?

Comment: You should end up with all positive semidefinite matrices of rank at least $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** It suffices to observe the following:

- If $A,B$ are positive semidefinite, then $\operatorname{rank}(A + B) \geq \operatorname{rank}(A)$
- For $r \geq 2$, any rank-$r$ matrix can be written in the form $\frac 12 (A + B)$ for some choice of positive semidefinite matrices $A,B$ of rank $r-1$.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! Could you please explain more about the second hint?

Comment: @Jesse Here's a further clue: if you can figure out how to do this for a diagonal rank-$r$ matrix, then you can extend this construction to the general case by diagonalization